# How to use the xili-language plugin?

Tags: plugins

Does anyone have any useful resources on how to use the xili-language plugin? I did not find any complete documentation from their part. I only found their blog with some examples but it's not so easy to understand.

I want to test xili-language to translate our site.

Comment: Please try to formulate specific issues you have trouble with (like installation, activation, doing something, etc).

Answer (score 2):

The [plugin's page in official repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/xili-language/) comes with considerable amount of notes and instructions.

There is also [developer's site](http://dev.xiligroup.com/?cat=393&lang=en_us) that looks quite extensive and [has forums](http://forum2.dev.xiligroup.com/).